# Need a list of all the people in Buddhas life

Tags: reference-request, the-buddha, sutras

I need a list of all the people mentioned in the Pali canon who were in the story of the historic Gautama the Buddha. For e.g. Angulimal, Ananda etc. I did a google search for the same but did not find the answer. Also, if you can provide sutta reference for their mention that will be great.

Answer (score 2):

Please try AccessToInsight (ATI)'s [Index of Proper Names](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/index-names.html).

On this page, please search for the following phrases:

- "Buddha's"
- "of the Buddha"

You will find phrases like "Buddha's father", "Buddha's cousin", "son of the Buddha", "Buddha's first meditation teacher", "half-brother of the Buddha", "Buddha's chief personal attendant" etc.

The ATI page will provide sutta references, if available.

For a description, please next refer to Palikanon's [Buddhist Dictionary of Pali Proper Names](http://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/dic_idx.html).

For example, on the ATI page, you can find:

> Suddhodana (Buddha's father): [Sn 3.11](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.3.11.than.html#suddhodana)

Then on Palikanon:

> - Suddhodana
>
> A Sākiyan Rājā of Kapilavatthu and father of Gotama Buddha.
>
> He was the son of Sihahanu and Kaccānā. His brothers were Dhotodana,
> Sakkodana, Sukkodana and Amitodana, and his sisters were Amitā and
> Pamitā.
>
> Māyā was his chief consort, and, after her death her sister Pajāpatī
> was raised to her position (Mhv.ii.15f.; Dpv.iii.45; J.i.15, etc.).

and it continues with further description on the Buddha's father, his life and background.